# TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable in python

Tags: python

I am trying to get the VM size of a running process and using the following simple script. Here initially I am trying to get the reference of that process. But getting the error as --

```
if "DomainManager" in c:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

---

```
import wmi

computer = wmi.WMI ()

for process in computer.Win32_Process ():

      c = process.CommandLine
      if "DomainManager" in c:
        print c
```

Would you please let me know the reason.

Thanks,
Rag

Comment: Try the interactive Python interpreter. It is your friend!  (Hint: `python -i myscript.py`). After the program exits, you're dropped to an interactive session with which you can inspect variables.

Answer (score 7):

```
import wmi
computer = wmi.WMI ()

for process in computer.Win32_Process ():
    c = process.CommandLine
    if c is not None and "DomainManager" in c:
        print c
```

Notice the condition in the `if` statement:

```
if c is not None and "DomainManager in c":
```

This will check to see if c is valid before attempting to check if the given string is a substring of it.

Apparently, some processes have no CommandLine as far as WMI is concerned.

Comment: Ohh.. yes...agf.... some processes do not have CommandLine. Just now I have confirmed it by printing commandlines of all processes. They have None. Now it's worked. Thanks agf.

Answer (score 2):

It appears

```
c = process.CommandLine
```

is setting `c` equal to `None`:

```
In [11]: "DomainManager" in None

TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

I don't know anything about the Win32 API, so this is a complete guess, but you might try:

```
if c and "DomainManager" in c:
```

Comment: This will work fine here because the empty string would not match anyway, but it's better to do `if c is not None` because that's the case generating the error, not the empty string.

Answer (score 1):

it means that `c` is `None` after the call to `process.CommandLine`. since `c` is `None`, it cannot be iterated over, so the `if`statement which follows, which iterate over `c` and tries to compare each items of `c` to `'DomainManager'`, cannot execute and throws an exception.

Comment: Nitpick: It's not a for loop.

Comment: oops: sorry i messed the for and the if... edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that `process.CommandLine` is returning `None` for some reason.