# Python TypeError is None for converted string

Tags: python, python-2.7, error-handling, typeerror

I am currently building a personal assistant bot as a challenge while I am on school break. It has previously had no issues, but I started getting TypeErrors, despite the fact that I am able to check that "speech" is  returning as a string. I know this because the TypeError will randomly pop up after a few times of running through the while True loop (so "speech" must only not be returning as a string then...)

I've found other pages on TypeErrors and things returning None and NonTypes like [one](http://I've%20found%20other%20pages%20on%20TypeErrors%20and%20things%20returning%20None%20and%20NonTypes%20like%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417403/typeerror-argument-of-type-nonetype-is-not-iterable%20and%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6762446/typeerror-argument-of-type-nonetype-is-not-iterable-in-python,%20but%20neither%20seem%20to%20help%20my%20predicament.) and [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417403/typeerror-argument-of-type-nonetype-is-not-iterable), but neither seem to help my predicament. I've also browsed through countless other pages trying to find things that help, but to no avail.

The error always brings up line 19:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
from chatterbot import ChatBot

import Messanger_Alert as MA
import Weather
import Email_Alert
import Chat
import Run


def start():
    #bot = Chat.start()
    MA_client = MA.login()
    print "Hello Luke!"
    print "I am ready for your command! :D"
    while True:
        speech = return_audio()
        try:
            if any(word in speech for word in ("Jason", "jason")): #This is line 19
                if any(word in speech for word in ("Message", "message", "Messenger", "messenger", "Facebook", "facebook")):
                    if any(word in speech for word in ("Send", "send")):
                        MA.send_message(MA_client) 
                        print "Ready for next command!"
                    elif any(word in speech for word in ("Search Friend", "search friend", "Seach friend", "search Friend", "friend", "Friend", "friends", "Friends")):
                        MA.friend_search(MA_client)
                        print "Ready for next command!"
                    elif any(word in speech for word in ("Check", "check")):
                        MA.check_message(MA_client)
                        print "Ready for next command!"
                elif any(word in speech for word in ("Email", "email")):
                    if any(word in speech for word in ("Personal", "personal", "Home", "home")):
                        Email_Alert.login1()
                        print "Ready for next command!"
                    elif any(word in speech for word in ("School", "school", "Dorm", "dorm", "UCSD", "ucsd")):
                        Email_Alert.login2()
                        print "Ready for next command!"
                elif any(word in speech for word in ("Weather", "weather", "Forecast", "forecast")):
                    Weather.decide()
                """else:
                    Chat.talk(bot)
            else:
                Chat.talk(bot)
                """
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            print "Error! Could not process that audio."
        except sr.RequestError as e:
            print "Error! No internet connection to Google Sound Recognizer."


def return_audio():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        speech = r.recognize_google(audio)
        try:
            speech = str(speech)
            print speech
            return speech
        except TypeError:
            print "Error! Could not convert speech to string!"
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print "Error! Could not process that audio."
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print "Error! No internet connection to Google Sound Recognizer."
```

This is the exact error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/lukec/PycharmProjects/Sysgen_AI/Run_File.py", line 25, in <module>
    startup()
  File "C:/Users/lukec/PycharmProjects/Sysgen_AI/Run_File.py", line 14, in startup
    voice()
  File "C:/Users/lukec/PycharmProjects/Sysgen_AI/Run_File.py", line 20, in voice
    Listen.start()
  File "C:\Users\lukec\PycharmProjects\Sysgen_AI\Listen.py", line 19, in start
    if any(word in speech for word in ("Jason", "jason")): 
  File "C:\Users\lukec\PycharmProjects\Sysgen_AI\Listen.py", line 19, in <genexpr>
    if any(word in speech for word in ("Jason", "jason")): 
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

I noticed that the TypeError arises more often when strange noises are heard that cannot be distinguished into words, but I don't get why. I first noticed this error when I had a Chatbot library conversation bot take over when a command wasn't being issued, and thought when I cut it out of my code the errors would stop, but that didn't fix it. Any help on fixing it and explaining why to me would be greatly appreciated.

If you'd need my extra files (Messanger_Alert, Weather, etc.), I'm willing to supply that code if it could possibly help.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `if any(word in speech for word in ("Jason", "jason")):`, Python is attempting to check whether either `word` is in `speech`. You get `speech` from `return_audio()`. When `return_audio()` encounters any of the specified exceptions, it does not execute any explicit `return` statement, therefore implicitly returning `None`, which can't be iterated over in search of anything.

To fix this, simply check whether that function produced a real result before you try to look through that result.

```
while True:
    speech = return_audio()
    if not speech:
        continue
```